# Cron script in apache with password

Tags: apache, cron, passwords

I want run a specific script  .php every day at midnight.  But this script i want That be necessary a password tô execute it's an cron. How can i do this in apache? I'm using a CentOS 7.

Comment: either pass the password as a parameter or create another script that will be able to do authentication.

Comment: Ok,  but how can i make a cron? schedule in Linux?  Like a cpanel cron

Comment: The first link on google: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html